# Let Button title label size according the device in swift (iPad or iPhone)

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, autolayout, uilabel

I have a question about button title label size.
 
I want to enlarge the font size which button title label in iPad.
 
I try to use following code, but it seems not working to make label enlarge.
 
If I want to according the device to change font size, what should I do?

Take image for example.
Label size like following image.
[image]

This code is nice size working in iPhone, but it seems very small in iPad.

```
func CustomButton() -> UIButton {
    let ui = UIButton()
    ui.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    ui.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
    return ui
}

class FullWidthButton: UIView {

var button:UIButton = { () -> UIButton in
    let ui:UIButton = CustomButton()
    ui.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 1
    ui.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    ui.titleLabel!.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
    ui.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
    ui.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0)
    ui.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    ui.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byClipping
    ui.backgroundColor = defaultButtonOrangeColor
    ui.layer.cornerRadius = defaultButtonRadius
    ui.layer.masksToBounds = true
    return ui
}()
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame:frame)
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    loadContent()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    loadVFL()
}

func loadContent() {

    addSubview(button)
}

func loadVFL() {

    button.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.width.height.leading.trailing.top.bottom.equalToSuperview()
    }   
} 
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39523476/changing-the-font-size-according-to-each-iphone-size

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48630776/uitextview-font-to-always-be-fixed-size/48646121#48646121' you can get answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [changing the font size according to each iPhone size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39523476/changing-the-font-size-according-to-each-iphone-size)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
ui.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0)
```

with

```
if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad{
        ui.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20.0)
}else if  UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone{
        ui.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0)
}else{
        //Unspecified
        ui.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
switch UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom { 
    case .phone:
    case .pad:
    case .unspecified:
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

```
if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height == 480 {
    // iPhone 4
    label.font = label.font.fontWithSize(20)     
} else if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height == 568 {
    // IPhone 5
    label.font = label.font.fontWithSize(20)
} else if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width == 375 {
    // iPhone 6
    label.font = label.font.fontWithSize(20)
} else if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width == 414 {
    // iPhone 6+
    label.font = label.font.fontWithSize(20)
} else if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width == 768 {
    // iPad
    label.font = label.font.fontWithSize(20)
}
```